# google analytics for windows 8.1 app

Tags: google-analytics, windows-8.1, google-analytics-sdk

I am using Google Analytics for a Windows 8.1 app. When I checked the events reports I could see the event category, action and label, but the value passed is not reflected. I want to know how to send more than 1 parameter value or custom events on a button click. For example, on a login button click I want to send the username, login time, screen name and additional details.

```
//code written
Tracker myTracker = EasyTracker.GetTracker();
myTracker.SendEvent("Login_event", "button_press", "login_button", 12);
```

Comment: Please format your question

Comment: @nyuen thanks for help in formatting but anyone pls help me wid the solution..

Comment: I am not familiar with GA for Windows, but can you clarify what you want to do? You mentioned you want to send more than one value (ie. the last parameter where you have a 12?) or send more than one event on the button click?